# Export java maven project with dependencies from IntelliJ as non-maven project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

How to export Java maven project with all dependencies from IntelliJ as non-maven project?

Comment: When you say export, what exactly do you mean? Are you going to migrate to a different build tool (like Ant)?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by that? Why do you want to export it as a non-maven project?

Comment: copy all jars in intellij and build new project in eclipse import your files than past jars and build your jars. you can easily maven in eclipse i dont know why you need this. but this is the way you can achieve that .

Comment: Is there any way to do this without eclipse? and only in intellij?

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy dependent jars in IntelliJ
2. Build new project in Eclipse
3. Import the project in Eclipse
4. Set the jars as dependencies in classpath of the project